# InvalidOperationException on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, savechanges

I am trying to delete one of my entities but I am receiving a strange error along it.

My code to delete one looks like this:

```
public bool Delete()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        context.Set(this.GetType()).Attach(this);
        context.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This method is part of my Entities and it attaches itself (the current entity) and changes the State to deleted.

On the line **context.SaveChanges();** I am receiving the error message:

**Translated Message (my own translation):**

The execution is aborted: The relation could not be changed, because for atleast one foreignkey property no NULL-value is allowed. When a relation is modified, the related foreignkey property is set on a NULL-value. If the foreignkey doesnt support NULL-value, you have to specify a new relation or set the foreignkeyproperty to a different NON-NULL-value or the non related object get deleted.

**Original Message:**

Der Vorgang ist fehlgeschlagen: Die Beziehung konnte nicht geändert werden, da für mindestens eine der Fremdschlüsseleigenschaften keine NULL-Werte zulässig sind. Wenn eine Beziehung geändert wird, wird die verwandte Fremdschlüsseleigenschaft auf einen NULL-Wert festgelegt. Wenn der Fremdschlüssel keine NULL-Werte unterstützt, muss eine neue Beziehung definiert, die Fremdschlüsseleigenschaft einem anderen Nicht-NULL-Wert zugeordnet oder das nicht verwandte Objekt gelöscht werden.

When I attach my object the relations seems to be intakt, once I change the state to Deleted the NavigationProperties get set to NULL, but why would EF try to change relations when I desire just a simple delete command?

**Edit:**

As recommended in the comments below.
I have set the Association between my Tables to have Cascade delete on, but for some reason it gets ignored.

Thats how my association looks like:

```
End1 Multiplicity - 1 (One of TabAdjust)
End1 Navigation Property - TabAdjustAccounts
End1 OnDelete - Cascade
End1 Role Name - TabAdjsut

End2 Multiplicity - * (collection of TabAdjustAccount)
End2 Navigation Property - TabAdjust
End2 OnDelete - None
End2 Role Name - TabAdjustAccount
Name - CS_TABADJUSTTABADJUSTACCOUNT
Referential Contraint - TabAdjust -> TabAdjustAccount
```

Its a 1:N relation between **TabAdjust** and **TabAdjustAccount**.

In my example I am trying to delete TabAdjust, the TabAdjustAccounts Navigation Property gets cleared once I change the state to deleted before that line the TabAdjustAccounts Property has items in it.

**Edit2:**

I am using DataBase first approach.

**Edit3:**

See my answer below maybe you can explain why this change makes a difference.

Comment: This is a formal way of saying that you are deleting a "parent" instance when one or more "child" instances still exist.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But why does changing the state to deleted clear all references if it wouldnt do this, the delete cascading should kick in but thats not the case.

Comment: Do you have the cascade on delete option enabled in EF?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes.

Comment: You should mention it in the question, because this appears to be very relevant: It looks that cascading deletes do not work for some reason in your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if its a bug or feature but when I change my code from this:

```
public bool Delete()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        context.Set(this.GetType()).Attach(this);
        context.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

To this:

```
public bool Delete()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        context.Set(this.GetType()).Attach(this);
        context.Set(this.GetType()).Remove(this); // <-- changed line...

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

everything is working fine and the cascade delete kicks in successfully.

I wont accept this as an answer because maybe someone knows why.

Answer (score 2):

In my own project this problem was oracle related. In Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.1.112.1 the call via "*context.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Deleted;*" worked fine.

After an update to 4.121.2.0 same problem occured, the cascading deletes doesnt fired anymore.

Your approach with "*context.Set(this.GetType()).Remove(this);*" worked for me too. But Oracles correct way for inserting and deleting objects is:

```
public bool Delete()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        context.MyEntityType.Remove(this); 
        //context.DeleteObject(this); <- in older versioned context

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

[Oracle Docu: inserting and deleting](http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm#t10)

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for "entity framework ignore cascade delete" found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17487948/1463649) to another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17487577/1463649).  You may need to enable the cascading delete on the dependent table:

`.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

Comment: This isnt valid for me since I am not using code-first approach and dont have a fluent-api that needs to call this method. I am using DataBase first and have a edmx file and I dont have a property for this setting.