# Delete object from database when it has dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cascading-deletes

I was trying to implement the Delete Action in the MVC3, but I got to the point that the object that I want to delete has dependencies in other tables and that's why I am getting:

> DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Here is my method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    repo.DeleteDirector(id);
    return View("index");
}
```

and this is how I am deleting it in my repository:

```
void DeleteDirector(int? id)
{
    Director d = dc.Directors.FirstOrDefault(dir => dir.Id == id);
    dc.Directors.Remove(d);
    dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

I was hoping that simple LINQ Remove method will do the job, but it won't. 
So I am trying to think of a way to efficiently remove it with all the dependencies. I know that I can do it manually by going through all the tables where particular Director  might be referenced. But I was hoping if Framework provides own implementation for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is one property in SQL `CasCade delete` which will enable dependencies to be deleted automatically when the parent record removed from the table.

By reviewing above code I am assuming you are using EF code first with repository pattern. If this is the case then you should provide Cascade delete in configuration. you can refer the below link

[Entity Framework (EF) Code First Cascade Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations)

I hope that will be helpful to you.