# Many to one relation with attached entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a many to many relation that I want to update using a detached entity that I have attached to the context (deserilized from WebApi).

I have created this helper method that works for Many to one relations

```
public void SetEntityState<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> source) where TEntity : EntityBase, IDeletable
{
    foreach (var deletable in source.ToList())
    {
        var entry = Entry(deletable);
        if (deletable.Deleted)
            entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        else
            entry.State = deletable.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Used like

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; 

db.SetEntityState(user.HomeFolders); //Works because HomeFolders is a many to one relation    
db.SetEntityState(user.Roles) //Does not work because Roles is a many to many relation
```

This does not ofcourse work with a Many to many relation because `entry.State = EntityState.Deleted` will point to the referenced enity and try to delete that instead of the row in the relation table.

So how can I delete/add many to many relations on a newly attached entity?

edit: Config

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(u => u.Id);

        Property(u => u.Username)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(u => u.Password)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        HasMany(s => s.HomeFolders)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(
                m => m.MapKey("UserId")
            );

        HasMany(p => p.Roles)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserRole");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });

        ToTable("User");
    }
}
```

Models

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Role : EntityBase,  IDeletable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HomeFolder> HomeFolders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**update:** Delete actually works if I remove the Role after the user is attached. But new roles that is in teh list will not be added

Update code as of latest revision, Add role still not working

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
{

    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SetEntityState(user.HomeFolders);
    user.Roles.Where(r => r.Deleted).ToList().ForEach(r => user.Roles.Remove(r));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
        db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = false;
    else
    {
        SetPassword(user);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: To delete you can use [cascade delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations). The SQL Server deletes all dependent records while deleting master record. I'm not sure about changing `State`, but the method `Add` can insert dependent records together with master record.

Comment: I tried just to remove the item from the collection  that did nothing, do you have an example?

Comment: sorry, I was just not very well understand your question.

Comment: I'm not trying to do a cascading delete, I'm trying to delete a relation between two entities User and Role

Comment: I found the [article](http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/solving-the-detached-many-to-many-problem-with-the-entity-framework/12505/#.VkxtBIvouUk) with similar technique. Author uses the `ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState` method. See chapter *Removing a many-to-many Relationship* in the article.

Comment: In my opinion, if you don't want to manipulate many to many associations as *independent associations* (i.e. without FK property) you should pull the junction class into the class model. Don't dive too deeply into the EF tracking mechanism. It makes you code hard to maintain when new EF versions are rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you chose the hard path and deal with `EntityState`?

Simply remove the roles, if `user` is attached:

```
user.roles.ToList().ForEach(r=> user.Roles.Remove(r))
```

Comment: I have tried that both before and after user is attached to context

Comment: Is this Code-First? If so, please post the model. Anyway, I'm not convinced modifying `EntityState` is the best solution...

Comment: Updated with config and models

Comment: Did you check state of attached user `Role`s ?

Comment: You didn't say about state of attached user `Role`s. If you attach `user` the `Role`s will get `UnChanged` state

Comment: But the Role is unchanged, its the UserRole relation that is changed

Comment: There is no `UserRole` relation in terms of POCO (C# classes). In C# you have to think in properties. When you manipulate `user.Roles` property then `user` is marked changed because one of its properties change. But when you attach that changed 'user', the already made changes will be lost. Why? Because a side effect of attaching an entity is marking it `Unchanged` and no matter what you have done to the entity, context thinks it's not changed. Hence, context exclude it to inspect the introduced changes

Comment: Could you please show me in code how I should make EF understand that roles have been added

Comment: First attach the user, then manipulate the relation i.e. `Roles` property.

Comment: But that is what I have done, db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; edit: I added db.Set<User>().Attach(user);
before setting state to Modified, changes nothing. Can remove roles, but new roles are not added