# Entity Framework, Cascade Delete with Code First - How?

Tags: entity-framework

I am relatively new to EF (V6) and am thoroughly confused by the myriad aspects of cascade delete and the settings affecting it. My main aim is to do all the required settings in code, and not to have to go to SQL Svr Mgmt Studio (SSMS) to tweak something; this is code-first, and I want the end-user to be able to create the database. My model, for tests, is simple:

Customer
Supplier
 
Address
 
A Customer has many Addresses
 
A Supplier has many Addresses
 
No Address is shared between Customer and Supplier
If I delete either a Customer or Supplier, the Address must be deleted at the same time

I prefer not to have any navigation properties in Address, but rather to keep Address just that, with no reference to its consumers. It is a general-purpose class after all.
Unless anyone can advise a better way, I have in fact made Address a base class of CAddress and SAddress, both of which classes could contain properties specific to Customer and Supplier addresses respectively. I end up with an Address table with a Discriminator column and an xx_id column for each Address type. It all sounds very simple, and it is surprising how difficult deleting has proved to be.

I now need to know how to reliably implement cascade delete. At present, the only way that I can get this to work is to load all Address children into memory (via .Include()) and also have a cascade delete rule set in SSMS. But (a) how, at any point, can I know if all children are in memory? and (b) I can't manually change the db design when the application is deployed.
I also found, at one point, that cascade deletion obviously worked in SSMS (delete parent and children are deleted too) but that this did not work from Remove()/SaveChanges() unless all children were loaded into memory. I had thought that cascade delete via an FK constraint obviated the need to load children in memory - yes? no?

Can someone please explain how to set up cascade deletion for my simple model, given so many possible players in the scenario: WillCascadeOnDelete, use of virtual, type of collection used, loading into memory (or not), lazy/eager loading, setting FK constraints manually/at runtime, use of fluent API and/or annotations, Remove(), DeleteObject(), removing children manually via foreach and the Remove()-ing parent... and so on.

My anticipation of useful replies has been eagerly loaded!
Note: this differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577) in that it refers to 1-to-many, no nav. props. and numerous other aspects of EF settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework (EF) Code First Cascade Delete for One-to-Zero-or-One relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations)

Comment: That example is not about 1-to-many, has navigation properties in the "child" and does not cover the other factors that I listed. Thanks.

Comment: How many FK do you have into your Address table? It seems you have two on efor Customer and another one for Supplier and both of them are nullable, right?

Comment: I don't want to explicitly declare anything in Address (e.g. a nav prop) because I want Address to be multi-use, and in desperation I got VS to produce the db from a model, just to see what it did, and yes, the physical table (not the class) has two FKs, both nullable.

Comment: Earlier answer deleted??? This is what it said:<br>you have no navigational properties Customer and Supplier and you don't want them on Address entity then EF Code First will generate a nullable FK  on the Address table because it thinks Address can exist w'out related Customer or Supplier hence will not activate the cascade deletion on those FKs.
You must add this fluent config:
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasMany(p => p.Addresses)
                               .WithOptional() // No Customer nav prop on Address; leave method empty
                               .WillCascadeOnDelete();