# Entities not cascade deleting, instead throwing error. How can I modify the relationship to allow this?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following relationship defined, where both `Customer` and `Retailer` are foreign keys to a `User`. So a `User` can be either a `Customer`, `Retailer` or both. Each `Customer` can have a list of `Retailer`s, and each `Retailer` can have a list of `Customer`s.

The relationship is defined as:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Retailer>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.User);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>() 
        .HasRequired(x => x.User);
}
```

with the entities defined as follows:

```
public class Retailer : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Retailer> Retailers { get; set; }
}

public class User : AbpUser<Tenant, User>
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Retailer Retailer { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to delete a `User` that has a `Customer` or `Retailer` foreign key, I get the error (either depending on the type of foreign key):

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Customers_dbo.AbpUsers_User_Id". The conflict occurred in database "ShopDB", table "dbo.Customers", column 'User_Id'.

or

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Retailers_dbo.AbpUsers_User_Id". The conflict occurred in database "ShopDB", table "dbo.Retailers", column 'User_Id'.

What do I need to change so that when I delete a `User` all foreign referenes to the `User` are also cascade deleted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework (EF) Code First Cascade Delete for One-to-Zero-or-One relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations)

Comment: As Eris mentioned, have you tried using .WillCascadeOnDelete() after HasRequired?

Comment: Not a duplicate, because cascded delete will cause the infamous "multiple cascade paths" exception. But @DaveDev, the user doesn't have foreign keys here. Customer and Retailer have foreign keys to User. With your configuration I would rather expect that EF will try to nullify these foreign keys, and fails. You don't seem to have shown the correct (or full) mapping.