# Entity Framework Cascade Delete fails when the FK is on the other end (right side)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entities and relationship designed using code first...

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;} //PK

    public ICollection<Child1> Children{get;set;} //one to many
}

public class Child1
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set;} //PK

   [ForeignKey("Parent")]
   public int ParentId {get; set;}

   public Parent { get; set;}

   public Child1Child Child1Child{ get; set; } //one to one Naviation
}

public class Child1Child
{
   [Key, ForeignKey("Child1")]
   public int Child1Id { get; set;} //PK & FK

   public Child1 { get; set; } //one to one
}
```

Now the Question is **deleting a Parent**, **should that not cascade the deletion to Child1 and Child1Child?**

In My case entity framework Cascades up to Child1 but not Child1child. Can some shed some light on what is going on here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to use fluent api to do this. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations)

Comment: But isn't cascade delete default behavior? I  tried WillCascadeOnDelete(), if that's what you want meant.

Comment: From a db perspective `ON DELETE CASCADE` needs to be defined between every parent and child table. From a model perspective, you can click on each relationship and set `CASCADE` for OnDelete option. With code first approach you need to override `OnModelCreating` and define `WillCascadeOnDelete` for both Parent and Child entities here. So that Parent will cascade delete the Child and the Child will cascade delete Child1Child

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause for the issue. **The Child1Child was not loaded** that caused the entity framework unaware of the Child1Child presence. Otherwise entity framework really cascades delete in this scenario. My bad :).