# Alter foreign key constraints after applying the migration Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I need to add a "cascade delete" constraint to a foreign key.

The migration for creating the foreign key is the last.

```
CreateTable(
   "dbo.DependentTable",
   c => new
   {
       ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
       SomeValue = c.Double(nullable: false),
   })
   .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
   .ForeignKey("dbo.IndependentTable", t => t.IndependentTableId)
   .Index(t => t.ID);
```

I just need to alter this line and re 'update-database'.

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.IndependentTable", t => t.IndependentTableId, cascadeDelete: true)
```

What I tried to do:

1. Comment code in `Down()` method to avoid losing the table and the data inside it.

   - roll-back to previous migration.
   - alter the line.
   - run `update-database`

   but I keep getting an error

   > There is already an object named 'dbo.DependentTable'
2. Generate New migration with `-IgnoreChanges`

   - Call these methods:

     ```
     DropForeignKey("dbo.DependentTable", "ID");
     AddForeignKey("dbo.DependentTable","ID","IndependentTable",cascadeDelete: true)
     ```
   - Run `Update-database`

   That also resulted in an error

   > There is already an object named 'FK_dbo.DependentTable_dbo.IndependentTable_Id' in the database. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Is there a way to add cascade delete to the foreign key without losing any data?

Comment: I believe you should be able to update your OnDelete action in the Context, then add a new migration and run it. Let EF do the work of creating the migration properly. See the answer here for how to define that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations

Comment: Honestly, Thank you so much, I don't get this part "you should be able to update your OnDelete action in the Context", but I followed the link and that helped a lot.